# Firebase html form

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build a form using Firebase as backend.

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email address...">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Subscribe</button>
</form>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
'use strict';

//grab a form
const form = document.querySelector('.form-inline');

//grab an input
const inputEmail = form.querySelector('#inputEmail');


//config your firebase push
const config = {
apiKey: "...",
authDomain: "...",
databaseURL: "...",
projectId: "...",
storageBucket: "...",
messagingSenderId: "...",
appId: "..."
};


//create a functions to push
function firebasePush(input) {


//prevents from braking
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

//push itself
var mailsRef = firebase.database().ref('emails').push().set(
{
mail: input.value
}
);

}

//push on form submit
if (form) {
form.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
firebasePush(inputEmail);

//shows alert if everything went well.
return alert('Data Successfully Sent to Realtime Database');
})
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get the following error on console:

```
TypeError: firebase.database is not a function
```

It refers to:

```
var mailsRef = firebase.database().ref('emails').push().set
```

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Realtime Database then under the current `<script>` that you have in your code, add the following:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

To be able to use the database in your website.